# iOS re-ask denied permission swift ios 11 || App rejected

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, eventkit

App got rejected for private API URl . 
Reason given by Apple 
Guideline 2.5.1 - Performance - Software Requirements

Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App Store.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to provide the associated functionality using public APIs or remove the functionality using the "prefs:root" or "App-Prefs:root" URL scheme.

Code Used

```
   {



  let status = EventManager.authorizationStatus(for: .event)


    if status == .notDetermined {
        EventManager.shared.requestAccess(to: .event) { (statuss, err) in

            if statuss {


               // self.Topview.removeSubviews()
              //  self.addCard(title: "You are good go", subtitle: "Enjoy")




            }
    }
    }


        if status == .authorized {


            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "takemeHome", sender: self)

        }else{


            let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!
            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl)


    }





}
```

Comment: If you sure that you aren't using any other prefs URL (have you checked any 3rd party frameworks you are using?) then you could appeal your rejection and explain that you are only using `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ios app store rejection - Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040558/ios-app-store-rejection-your-app-uses-the-prefsroot-non-public-url-scheme)