# ios app store rejection - Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, app-store-connect

I recently uploaded a new version of my app to itunes connect. My app got rejected with this note

> Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme

I am almost sure that I don't use any Url scheme on my app I have tried finding prefs:root using `grep -R` in my entire project through terminal (case insensitive to be able to also match App-Prefs or whatever.

I also use a lot of cocoapods libraries so... my question is ...
Is there a way to find out which library is using that permission?

Screenshot of search results on xcode

[image]

Frameworks used on my project:

- AmazonFling
- many others from CocoaPods (not listed because irrelevant: see my answer)

Comment: I also faced that issue Would you like to check is there any "App-Prefs:root=" url is opened through app ? If yes Then this is the main cause because these are not a Public Url Schemes

Comment: For Searching the entire project search through Xcode Search pannel

Comment: I need to check where on my app I use that because I cannot find it and apprenttly apple does

Comment: UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard")!) only this API is allowed other are not.

Comment: Check through Whole code even though the cocoapods too. They Might use this

Comment: Other way is give support to app from iOS9.3 Onwords by which they are allowed.

Comment: I have just added a screenshot of xcode search results

Comment: I also confused How it is possible if not used then how this issue occures. I think just try to submit build again hope so it will be live sometimes this also helps.

Comment: I will try to resubmit as I have no clue where the error may be. Please everyone feel free to comment your thougts

Comment: No need to resubmit it, just ask more detail on itunesconnect from Apple tester.

Comment: I have already asked for more details and no answer from them.. anyone know how much time does they take to answer?

Comment: The question I did to apple was "wich command should I use to check if my app is ussing that api" (something like this is not exactly what I wrote)

Comment: I've searched all the pods: the culprit is likely one that is not open-source and that is obfuscating the string like JSQMessagesViewController did in the past when they wrote [`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"_U", @"IRotat", @"ingAlertController"]`](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/blob/f52e83bdb4d5c19ecfd5b6e54cdb9f2efa66cfcf/JSQMessagesViewController/Controllers/JSQMessagesViewController.m) to bypass detection of illegal use of `"_UIRotatingAlertController"`. If you're able to pinpoint the culprit in the future, don't forget to share the name!

Comment: At the end the one with the issues was AmazonFling that was not listed on the pods because was installed ussing another method. AmazonFling does not have update yet so it was removed until they update it

Answer (score 26):

I faced the same rejection form Apple and to open app settings i was using the below code and it's not accepted on iOS11.

```
let url = URL(string : "prefs:root=")
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
 }
```

So, to open Settings, I updated the code and It worked.

```
guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {
    return
  }
  if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl)  {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
      })
    }
    else  {
      UIApplication.shared.openURL(settingsUrl)
    }
  }
```

Comment: I got rejected too, due to `prefs:root=` issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51093121/419348

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I resolved it as following:-

**Step 1:-** Search for the **Prefs:root** in your app then you will find something as follows:-

```
 if let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION") {
 // If general location settings are disabled then open general location settings
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
 }
```

**Step 2:-** Change the above code section with the following one:-

```
 if let url = URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) 
 {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
 }
```

Now rebuild your app and resubmit to the App Store with no worries :)

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue. "prefs:root=" url scheme is not accepted by iOS 11. Using the **UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString** value fixed it.

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK2Ka.png)

Comment: Being up-to-date with the guidelines is the best way to avoid such issues.

Answer (score 2):

if you need to find with the 'prefs:root is:

Go to your project's target -> then Info -> then URL Types, there you should find URL Schemes with value like 'prefs' or 'prefs:root'

Comment: App Store will reject apps which use pres:root

Guideline 2.5.1 - Performance - Software Requirements


Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.￼

Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

At the end the one with the issues was AmazonFling that was not listed on the pods because was installed using another method. See the forums post about it: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/167282/apple-app-rejected-because-of-non-public-apis-refe.html

AmazonFling does not have update yet (as of Apr 27, 2018) so I removed it until they update it.

---

Fixed in AmazonFling 1.3.2, released on the same day. See https://developer.amazon.com/fr/docs/fling/release-notes.html

Comment: According to other users of the AmazonFling API, the Apple error message was actually "_"Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs: com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete "_". And this one is findable with `grep -R 'com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete'`

Comment: Apple tell me about springboard later on.. but thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

We also faced the same issue and resolved it by this:

```
if let url = URL(string:UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)

    {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To find out which library is using that permission, you can use this command in terminal

```
strings <file path> | grep 'prefs:root'
```

to search in dependencies compiled files, if you have no luck with search in Xcode.