# iOS App Store Rejection - Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non public URL scheme. Is there any testable fix?

Tags: ios, swift

So while submitting the app to the appstore, we get this response back:

[image]

I've been reviewing some answers on here [and this solution might be doable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040558/ios-app-store-rejection-your-app-uses-the-prefsroot-non-public-url-scheme), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to encorporate the fix into this codebase I'm working in.

Also, and most importantly, how can I make sure this won't get rejected again if I think I fix it.  Is there any way to test whether or not this app fix will lead to a successful submission?

Here is the snippet of code that needs to change:

```
    static func openSettingsAlert(_ title: String, message: String, settingsURL: String) -> UIAlertController {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { (_) -> Void in
        let settingsURL = URL(string: settingsURL)
        if let url = settingsURL {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            })
        }
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(settingsAction)

    return alertController
}
```

Thank you for any insights you can provide into this matter.

Thanks

Comment: you can use UIApplication.openSettingsURLString it will approved

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Could you possibly reply with your suggested usage within this context?   Also, UIApplication.openSettingsURLString still takes in a URL String parameter and what if the value for that URL String is still "prefs:root="?

Comment: I have used `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` in one of the my app and apple . never raised question on it.

Comment: `UIApplication.openSettingsURLString` is in Apple official documents. It's in public document. [I got rejected too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51093121/419348) for `prefs:root=` reason, due to it's treated as private API.

Comment: @AechoLiu, when you switched to UIApplication.openSettingsURLString, did you still pass in the original "prefs:root=" String, or did you have to switch to something else.  Will Apple still have a problem with me passing "prefs:root=FACEBOOK" as a parameter into this newer method? Thanks.

Comment: I did pass the app review, after switch to UIApplication.openSettingsURLString. And ask my boss to update UI spec due to this issue.

Comment: @AechoLiu, did you have to change the values at all or just the method?

Comment: In Apple official document, only `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` is valid. [I had post the same complaint before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51093121/419348). In my app, the UI needs to go to `WiFi` settings. But now no public API for it. The final UI spec is a graph which guide user to the WiFi page by himself.

Comment: Thank you for your insights @AechoLiu , I'll look into this further

Answer (score -2):

I think you can reply in your reject message form to apple, tell them your app no use "prefs:root="~ (PS. remenber attach your code screenshot) ..
after this, re-upload app to waiting for review

Comment: I believe my client would still like the ability to share on social media. Wouldn't that be misleading to apple?  I think it still needs that functionality

Comment: okay, just because even i happed this by apple rejected, and i take screen 「xcode find "prefs:root=" 」and reply apple, resubmit it's safe...