How to open System notification app settings page in react-native (iOS)
I am trying to use Linking.openURL(App-Prefs:NOTIFICATIONS_ID&path=${bundleId}); to open the system notifications setting page for the app but it is just opening phone's settings.
Does anybody know how to achieve that? If above is the correct approach, are there any requirements/configurations, from a project point of view, that i should check/add for that to work (iOS 14)?
ty

Direct access to the app's notifications section via code is not possible on iOS 14. The only way is to open the app's general settings, and the user will be able to navigate to the desired section themselves.
Linking.openSettings();


I see... Linking.openSettings(); also opens the general setting page for me rather than the app's setting page. Is there anything that i might be missing? Also, would you know from which iOS version might be possible to target the app's notifications section?

On my device with iOS 17.6.1, react-native 0.71 and Linking.openSettings() opens the app settings where you can select ‘Notifications’.
I also want to warn you that apps using ‘App-Prefs:’ will be rejected when published to the AppStore.
"Your app is using a non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not allowed in the App Store, as it may result in a degraded user experience if these APIs are changed."
So the only way to properly open the settings is to use Linking.openSettings().

Can you post the iOS and react-native versions you are testing opening settings on, maybe I can figure it out.


react-native > v0.72.6.
iOS deployment target > 14.0
emualtor > iOS17.5

Regarding AppStore rejecting when using App-Prefs:’, I'll keep that in mind.
Requirements atm are to be able to send the user to the notifications setting page directly.
If not possible, i guess we'll have to revisit that.
Being able to at least open up the app's setting page rather than the genral setting would be a start though :)

Try testing this on a real device, that might be the problem

It seems to be working on a real device on browserstack. Do you know if anything needs to be done in order to have the same behaviour on an emulator? or emulators just don't allow for that?      Also, we recently submitted an app for review, which contained Linking.openURL(App-Prefs:NOTIFICATIONS_ID&path=${bundleId}); (behind feature flag) and it was not rejected. Would you know if rejection only happens when trying to use the old approach (prefs:root=... etc) ?

Apple points out that many hardware features may not work on simulators. I don't think you can do anything about it except test the app on a real device.
I don't know much about rejected builds, but here are a couple of discussions:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/115981
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040558/ios-app-store-rejection-your-app-uses-the-prefsroot-non-public-url-scheme
I will be glad if you mark my answers as useful
